# Need a reference site for asp.net in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i need a any site in which i can get a basic information of asp.net and how it is work with c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft is a good place to start:

http://www.asp.net/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336766.aspx
http://www.asp.net/aspnet-4/videos

W3 schools
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp

http://www.fincher.org/tips/Languages/csharp.shtml

[Google User Groups for .Net](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS381US381&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=.net+user+groups)

Answer (score 2):

[4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/) is a really good ASP.NET site.  It has better tutorials and examples than Microsoft.  No matter what you are trying to do they've probably got an example of how to do it.

Microsoft's MSDN site is the best one to go to for reference and definitions of either [ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd566231.aspx) or [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx37x362.aspx).

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp) while not very in depth or advanced is easy to understand and will give you the basics.  They only delve into ASP.NET 2.0 though so if you are looking for 4.0 resources I would look at the other sites.